# What is the fastest way to find newline characters in Rust?

Tags: rust, parallel-processing, wc

I'm new to Rust and I'm trying to write a version of the Linux `wc` utility in Rust. Specifically, I want it to be able to get the number of lines in an extremely large files—GiBs or larger—rather quickly—I'm comparing it to `wc`.

Here are the functions in question:

```
pub fn par_get_number_of_lines(path: &PathBuf) -> Result<(), io::Error>  {
    let input: File = File::open(&path)?;
    let file_size: usize = get_file_size(&path) as usize;
    let cores: u64 = available_parallelism().unwrap().get() as u64;
    let buffered: BufReader<File> = BufReader::new(input);
    let buff_capacity: usize = buffered.capacity();
    let buffer_segments: u64 = (file_size).div_ceil(buff_capacity) as u64;
    let segments_per_core: u64 = buffer_segments / cores;
    let mut remaining_bytes: u64 = buffer_segments % cores;
    let mut assignments: Vec<( u64, u64, u64)> = vec![];
    let mut cursor_location = 0;
    for core in 0..cores {
        let mut end = cursor_location + (segments_per_core  * buff_capacity as u64);
        if remaining_bytes > 0{
            end = cursor_location + ((segments_per_core + 1) * buff_capacity as u64);
            remaining_bytes -= 1;
        } else if core == cores {
            end = get_file_size(&path) as u64;
        }
        let assignment = (cursor_location, end, 0);
        assignments.push( assignment);
        cursor_location = end + 1;
    }

    let mut total_lines: Arc<Mutex<u64>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
    let mut path = path;
    let mut handle_vec: Vec<thread::JoinHandle<()>> = vec![]; // JoinHandles will go in here
    for assign in assignments{
        let total_lines_clone = Arc::clone(&total_lines);
        let path_clone = path.clone();
        let handle = std::thread::spawn(move || {
            *total_lines_clone.lock().unwrap() += read_part_of_file(path_clone, assign.0, assign.1);
        });
        handle_vec.push(handle);
    }
    handle_vec.into_iter().for_each(|handle| handle.join().unwrap());
    println!("Total lines {:?}", total_lines);
    Ok(())
}
fn read_part_of_file(path: PathBuf, start: u64, end: u64) -> u64{
    let input: File = File::open(&path).unwrap();
    let mut buffered: BufReader<File> = BufReader::new( input);
    buffered.seek(SeekFrom::Start(start as u64)).unwrap();
    let buf_size: u64 = (end - start) as u64;
    let reader: io::Take<BufReader<File>> = buffered.take(buf_size);
    let lines = reader.bytes().filter(
            |b| 
            Some(b.as_ref().unwrap())== Some(&('\n' as u8))
        )
        .count();    
    lines as u64
}
```

I was able to get pretty close to `wc` in terms of performance by using Rayon, but ran into an issue. My approach was to create an evenly distributed list of start and end bytes per core, and use `BufReader::SeekFrom` and `::Take` for each thread to read from those parts of the file. The problem was that when I used `lines()` it counted an EOF as a newline character. So, when a segment from one thread ended mid sentence it counted that as a newline and then the actual newline starting in the next segment was counted by the next thread. The result was a fast, but inaccurate program.

To fix the issue, I try to search for `'\n'`. The result was accurate but MUCH SLOWER. It seems like there has to be a solution that is as fast, or nearly as fast as `wc`. I have spent hours looking for a solution. The closest thing was an article about writing `wc` in Rust, but the approach is significantly different and a bit over my head as a newbie. Any suggestions that can improve this program?

Comment: First things first - are you compiling with `--release`? Also note that your disk I/O is going to be a major bottleneck for this sort of work.

Comment: Does a segment with a single newline at the end get counted as having one newline or two? i.e., does the EOF still count if it's preceded by a newline? If two, then you can just subtract one from each count, since the EOF will always be there. (If you want to count the EOF at the very end of the file, you might need a bit more cleverness.)

Comment: @BallpointBen: I assume they're following what `wc -l` does, which is to count the raw newline characters. If the file ends in a newline, it counts. If the final line doesn't end with a newline, it's not a line.

Comment: Adding to @ColonelThirtyTwo: It's *extremely* unlikely that threading will help here, because it would mean greater I/O contention. On a flash drive, it probably won't *hurt* much, but on a spinning disk drive you're going to force the head to seek around a lot more, creating a ton of seek latency that reading sequentially wouldn't incur. [`wc` itself is strictly sequential](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/wc.c).

Comment: I wonder if UTF-8 decoding is playing a part here as `wc` does not have to contend with that at all.

Comment: [*"Seeking always discards the internal buffer, even if the seek position would otherwise fall within it."*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#impl-Seek-for-BufReader%3CR%3E) might be an issue, too, unless of course your reads are bigger then 8k at which point the `BufRead` becomes completely useless and always bypassed.

Comment: @tadman I don't see any UTF-8 decoding happening in this code. It looks like purely byte I/O, which is all that is required since `b'\n'` cannot possibly be part of a multi-byte character.

Comment: The wc implementation interleaves reading from disk with counting newline characters. On processors supporting the avx2 extension, wc uses these instructions to speed up counting the newline characters. If you want to match wc speed, you either need to implement that optimization, or you need to find a different optimization, e.g. having one thread read the data alternating between two buffers, and a second thread do the counting. You shouldn't read from the file in more than one thread.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, no, I'm not compiling with --release. Yes, great point on the I/O bottleneck.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, regarding I/O bottleneck. Yes, I was concerned about that. However, in the current, albeit inaccurate, version, using parallelization resulted in 12x speedup on my system. Now, wc, which as tadman pointed out, is strictly sequential, is still much faster.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, that is very interesting! Thank you for pointing that out. I'll have to look into that optimization. Any suggestions on how to implement that? How would you do the matching for the newline?

Comment: @nik88: Yeah, if you're not compiling with `--release`, then none of your benchmarks matter. Without optimizations, it doesn't optimize away the iterator overhead and the like (all those classes have to actually *exist* on some level in the compiled binary). In my local tests, just about any reasonable implementation of `wc` in Rust (buffered reader reading blocks and doing discrete sums, using `memmap` and straight up counting newlines, etc.), compiled in `--release` with `lto = true` configured in the `Cargo.toml` would process a largish file using about 3-4x the time of `wc -l`.

Comment: Going slower is expected given `wc -l` optimizes the hell out of the newline counting (e.g. using AVX2 when available, and even when it isn't, it reuses a single buffer for bulk read followed by count loop, and it goes to the trouble of dynamically switching modes for counting lines based on how many lines it's been seeing recently, since the optimal counting strategy changes based on relative line frequencies). You can [examine it yourself](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/f40c6b5cf20f6524c5775919c195c7638069d676/src/wc.c#L249); matching it in Rust would require heavy optimization.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, thanks! Yes, you were correct about the unoptimized code being the problem. Duh. Silly me.

The naive version of my code, optimized with --release, takes about 5x what wc takes. Now--and this my be interesting for some--the parallel version of my code, optimized with --release, is marginally faster than the GNUs wc.

I did notice there is an off by one error in the parallel code, but that doesn't seem relevant to the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Per @ShadowMaster: the fix was simply adding the --release flag to the build.